# fix issue documentary evidence for radio app in appstore

Tags: app-store

I developed a radio app and when I wanted to submit it to AppStore, it rejected my app with the underneath issue, but it is impossible to get documentary evidence form about 5000 online stations, so is there any way to solve it?

> Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal

> Your app contains content or features that may violate the rights of one or more third parties. Specifically, your app provides potentially unauthorized access to third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services.

> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights, you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.

> Next Steps

> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app.

> In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: @MuhammadAwais Unfortunately nothing yet, I realized I must receive an evidence document from all Radio stations that I used in my App.

Comment: Strange.. now my application update stuck at this point and I am having this feeling that this is the end for my application because can't get document evidence for hundreds of stations :(

Comment: Hi  it seems that i have the same problem , after two years working on my radio app i've just noticed about Guideline 5.2.3 and obviously i can't get the document evidence from thousand and thousand of station , so it's the end for me as well ! i wonder how tunein and Audials and many other have done to get those document :( so sad about it !!

Comment: Hello alls. Is this issue resolved. I have same problem how can I Proceed. @mohsen

Comment: Hi @nebyan , Not yet :)

Comment: And today? was it solved?

Comment: @LetsGoBrandon Not yet for me

Comment: @mohsen any update?

Comment: @eemrah unfortunately noting yet.